# DynamicMethod - Common language runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: c#, invoke, dynamicmethod, opcodes

So I try to call a method from an extern DLL via a dynamicmethod using the ilgenerator.

```
delegate void Write(string text);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"externmethod.dll");
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
    var method = assembly.GetTypes()[0].GetMethod("Write");
    var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("Write", typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    var ilGenerator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
    ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, null);
    var delegateVoid = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Write)) as Write;
    delegateVoid("test");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the DLL code:

```
using System;
class program
{
    public static void Write(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this strange error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidProgramException' occurred in test.exe
>   Additional information: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

And I don't have any clue what im doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate `delegate void Write(string text);` accepting string as parameter so you need to do this before emitting `call`:

```
ilGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldstr, "this is test");
```

And you must return in the end of the method so you need to do that:

```
ilGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);
```

Complete code:

```
var method = assembly.GetTypes()[0].GetMethod("Write");
var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("Write", typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(string) });
var ilGenerator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldstr, "this is test");
ilGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Call, method);
ilGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);
var delegateVoid = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Write)) as Write;
delegateVoid("test");
```

**Update**: I noticed that you want to send parameter to method so instead of

```
ilGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldstr, "this is test");
```

Write this

```
ilGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
```

Then what you send here `delegateVoid("test");` will print out.

And about the access limitation, if you can't make `Program` class public, you can define your `DynamicMethod` like this to get access:

```
var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("Write", typeof(void), new[] { typeof(string) }, assembly.GetTypes()[0]);
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it gives me another error;

Comment: Errormessage:Additional information: Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.Write(System.String)' to access method 'program.Write(System.String)' failed.

Comment: @JustusBosschieter This is `MethodAccessException`. Make `Program` class `public`.

Comment: You can use skipVisibilityCheck = true when create the DynamicMethod instead of changing your program scope.